# connection.commit inserts only last row in jsp

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

I have a JSP from which I'm calling a servlet to read an excel document and insert data to a MySQL database by reading the excel cell by cell. When I upload the excel with data, only the last row of the excel document gets inserted. I have commit and rollback also. Even if everything goes well while debugging. There is no error thrown. It goes till commit but only the last row is inserted.

```
public class AddUser extends HttpServlet {

    // location to store file uploaded
    private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "user";

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    String file_error = "";
    String message_failure = "message_failure_user";
    String message_success = "message_success_user";
    String message_failure_bulk = "message_failure_bulk";
    String message_success_bulk = "message_success_bulk";
    String message_success1 = "message_success1";
    String db_error = "Database error has occurred.";
    String success = "Added the user successfully.";
    String user_type, first_name, last_name, user_number, email_id, user_status, login_id, group_name, submit_value;
    String sms_url, SenderID, mail_user,/* mail_password,*/ password_path, playstore_link, webapp_link;
    List<String> type, names, numbers, email_ids, passwords, login_ids, group_names;
    IST ist;
    AESCrypt aESCrypt;

    public void connectToServer() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException, IOException {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream propertiesStream = contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
        properties.load(propertiesStream);
        String url = properties.getProperty("jdbc.url");
        String driver = properties.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
        String username = properties.getProperty("jdbc.username");
        String password = properties.getProperty("jdbc.password");
        sms_url = properties.getProperty("jdbc.sms_url");
        SenderID = properties.getProperty("jdbc.sms_senderid");
        mail_user = properties.getProperty("jdbc.sender_mailid");
        //  mail_password = properties.getProperty("jdbc.sender_mailpass");
        password_path = properties.getProperty("jdbc.password_path");
        playstore_link = properties.getProperty("jdbc.playstore_link");
        webapp_link = properties.getProperty("jdbc.webapp_link");

        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ist = new IST();
        aESCrypt = new AESCrypt();
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fileName = "";

        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent((HttpServletRequest) request)) {
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println("Error: Form must has enctype=multipart/form-data.");
            writer.flush();
            return;
        }

        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload((FileItemFactory) factory);

        String uploadPath = String.valueOf(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("")) + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;
        File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdir();
        }
        File storeFile = null;

        try {
            List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            String ext = null;
            if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0) {
                for (FileItem item : formItems) {
                    if (item.isFormField()) {
                        if ("submituser".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            submit_value = item.getString().trim();
                        } else if ("user_type".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            user_type = item.getString().trim();
                        } else if ("first_name".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            first_name = item.getString().trim();
                        } else if ("last_name".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            last_name = item.getString().trim();
                        } else if ("user_number".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            user_number = item.getString().trim();
                        } else if ("email_id".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            email_id = item.getString().trim();
                        } else if ("user_status".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            user_status = item.getString().trim();
                        } else if ("login_id".equals(item.getFieldName())) {
                            login_id = item.getString().trim();
                        }
                    } else {
                        fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                        ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
                        String randomFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                        fileName = randomFileName + "." + ext;

                        String filePath = String.valueOf(uploadPath) + File.separator + fileName;
                        storeFile = new File(filePath);
                        item.write(storeFile);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (submit_value.equals("Add")) {
                connectToServer();
                file_error = "";
                String sql_query = "SELECT * from user_account where mobile_no=" + user_number;
                ResultSet resultset_val = statement.executeQuery(sql_query);
                if (resultset_val.next()) {
                    file_error = "Mobile number entered is already in use. Please enter  a different number.";
                }
                if (email_id.length() != 0) {
                    String sql_query1 = "SELECT * from user_account where email_id='" + email_id + "'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val1 = statement.executeQuery(sql_query1);
                    if (resultset_val1.next()) {
                        file_error = file_error + "<br/>Email id entered is already in use. Please choose a different email id.";
                    }
                }

                String sql_query2 = "SELECT * from user_account where login_id='" + login_id + "'";
                ResultSet resultset_val2 = statement.executeQuery(sql_query2);
                if (resultset_val2.next()) {
                    file_error = file_error + "<br/>Login id entered is already in use. Please choose a different Login id.";
                }
                URL connectURL = new URL(password_path);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        connectURL.openStream()));

                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    password.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                //AESCrypt aESCrypt = new AESCrypt();
                String encrypted = AESCrypt.bytesToHex(aESCrypt.encrypt(password.toString()));

                if (!file_error.equals("")) {
                    throw new Exception();
                } else {
                    statement.executeUpdate("insert into user_account(user_type_id,first_name,last_name,mobile_no,email_id,status,login_id,password,login_flag,last_gen_pw_ts,last_updated_ts)values('" + user_type + "','" + first_name + "','" + last_name + "','" + user_number + "','" + email_id + "','" + user_status + "','" + login_id + "','" + encrypted + "',0,'" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "')", java.sql.Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

                }
                connection.commit();
//                SendSMS1(user_type, first_name, user_number, password.toString(), login_id);
//                if (!email_id.isEmpty()) {
//                    SendMail1(user_type, first_name, email_id, password.toString(), login_id);
//                }

            } else if (submit_value.equals("Submit")) {
                file_error = "";
                String excelfile = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                if (ext.equals("xls")) {
                    File inputFile = new File(excelfile);
                    readXls(inputFile);
                } else {
                    File inputFile = new File(excelfile);
                    readXlsx(inputFile);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                if (submit_value.equals("Add")) {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                    session.setAttribute(message_success1, submit_value);
                    session.setAttribute(message_failure, file_error);

                    session.setAttribute("user_type", user_type);
                    session.setAttribute("login_id", login_id);
                    session.setAttribute("f_name", first_name);
                    session.setAttribute("l_name", last_name);
                    session.setAttribute("m_no", user_number);
                    session.setAttribute("e_id", email_id);
                    session.setAttribute("u_status", user_status);
                    response.sendRedirect("userNew.jsp");
                } else if (submit_value.equals("Submit")) {
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                    session.setAttribute(message_success1, submit_value);
                    if(file_error.equals("")){
                        session.setAttribute(message_failure_bulk, db_error);
                    }else{
                    session.setAttribute(message_failure_bulk, file_error);
                    }
                    response.sendRedirect("userNew.jsp");
                }
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.rollback();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                session.setAttribute(message_failure, db_error);
                response.sendRedirect("userNew.jsp");
            }
        } finally {
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY));
            if (file_error.equals("")) {
                if (submit_value.equals("Add")) {
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    int user_limit = checkUserLimit();
                    if (user_limit == 0) {
                        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                        out.println("alert('" + success + ". You have exceeded the active users limit. Please upgrade the subscription.');");
                        out.println("location='userList.jsp';");
                        out.println("</script>");
                    } else {
                        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                        session.setAttribute(message_success1, submit_value);
                        session.setAttribute(message_success, success);
                        response.sendRedirect("userNew.jsp");
                    }
                } else if (submit_value.equals("Submit")) {
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    int user_limit = checkUserLimit();
                    if (user_limit == 0) {
                        out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
                        out.println("alert('" + success + ". You have exceeded the active users limit. Please upgrade the subscription.');");
                        out.println("location='userList.jsp';");
                        out.println("</script>");
                    } else {
                        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                        session.setAttribute(message_success1, submit_value);
                        session.setAttribute(message_success_bulk, success);
                        response.sendRedirect("userNew.jsp");
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                if (!statement.isClosed()) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
                session.setAttribute(message_failure, db_error);
                response.sendRedirect("userNew.jsp");
            }
        }
    }

    public void readXlsx(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {

        connectToServer();
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        if (wb.getSheet("Users") == null) {
            file_error = file_error + "<br/>Sheet 'Users' not found in uploaded file.";
            throw new Exception();
        }
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Users");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        getValue(rowIterator);
    }

    public void readXls(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
        connectToServer();

        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        if (wb.getSheet("Users") == null) {
            file_error = file_error + "<br/>Sheet 'Users' not found in uploaded file.";
            throw new Exception();
        }
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Users");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        getValue(rowIterator);
    }

    public void getValue(Iterator<Row> rowIterator) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception,
            ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        List<String> inserts = new ArrayList<>();

        type = new ArrayList<>();
        names = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        email_ids = new ArrayList<>();
        passwords = new ArrayList<>();
        login_ids = new ArrayList<>();
        group_names = new ArrayList<>();
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        int count = 1, allowed_limit = 0;
        boolean error = false;
        rowIterator.next();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            row = rowIterator.next();
            error = false;
            count = count + 1;
            ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                cell = row.getCell(i);

                if (cell == null) {
                    array.add("");
                    continue;
                }
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        array.add("" + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        array.add("" + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue().trim());
                        array.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        array.add("" + cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (array.get(0).equals("") && array.get(1).equals("") && array.get(2).equals("") && array.get(3).equals("") && array.get(4).equals("") && array.get(5).equals("") && array.get(6).equals("") && array.get(7).equals("")) {
                break;
            } else {
                String status_check = array.get(6).trim();
                if (status_check.equals("Active")) {
                    allowed_limit = allowed_limit + 1;
                }
            }
            if (!getUserLimit().equals("")) {
                int getUserLimits = Integer.parseInt(getUserLimit());
                if (allowed_limit > getUserLimits) {
                    file_error = "<br/>You have exceeded the active users limit. Please upgrade the subscription.";
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }

            user_type = array.get(0).trim();
            login_id = array.get(1).trim();
            first_name = array.get(2).trim();
            last_name = array.get(3).trim();
            user_number = array.get(4).trim();
            email_id = array.get(5).trim();
            user_status = array.get(6).trim();
            group_name = array.get(7).trim();

            if (numbers.contains(user_number)) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Duplicate mobile number found.";
                error = true;
            }
            if (email_ids.contains(email_id)) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Duplicate Email Id found.";
                error = true;
            }

            if (login_ids.contains(login_id)) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Duplicate Login Id found.";
                error = true;
            }
            names.add(first_name);
            numbers.add(user_number);
            if (!group_name.equals("")) {
                group_names.add(group_name);
            }
            if (!email_id.equals("")) {
                email_ids.add(email_id);
            }
            login_ids.add(login_id);

            String exp1 = "^[a-z|A-Z|]+[a-z|A-Z|0-9]*";
            if (login_id.equals("") || login_id.length() < 3) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide a Login ID with minimum 3 characters";
                error = true;
            }
            if (!login_id.isEmpty()) {
                if (login_id.length() > 30) {
                    file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide a Login ID within 30 characters.";
                    error = true;
                } else if (!login_id.matches(exp1)) {
                    file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide a Login ID with first letter alphabet";
                    error = true;

                } else {
                    ResultSet resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery("select user_id from user_account where login_id='" + login_id + "'");
                    if (resultSet1.next()) {
                        file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Login id entered is already in use. Please choose a different Login id.";
                        error = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (user_type.equals("")) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please enter a valid user type.";
                error = true;
            }

            String name_reg = "[A-Za-z ]*";
            if (first_name.equals("") || first_name.length() < 3) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please enter a first name with minimum three characters length.";
                error = true;
            } else if (first_name.length() > 30) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide first name with length less than 30 characters.";
                error = true;
            } else if (!first_name.matches(name_reg)) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": First name contain only alphabets and space.";
                error = true;
            }

            if (!last_name.isEmpty()) {
                if (last_name.length() > 30) {
                    file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide last name with length less than 30 characters.";
                    error = true;
                } else if (!last_name.matches(name_reg)) {
                    file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Last name contain only alphabets and space.";
                    error = true;
                }
            }

            String exp = "[1-9][0-9]{9}";
            if (user_number.equals("") || user_number.length() < 10 || user_number.length() > 10) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please enter a valid 10 digits mobile number.";
                error = true;
            } else if (!user_number.matches(exp)) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please enter a valid 10 digits mobile number.";
                error = true;
            } else {
                user_number = user_number.split("\\.")[0];
                for (int x = 0; x < user_number.length(); x++) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(user_number.charAt(x))) {
                        file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please enter a valid 10 digits mobile number starting with 9, 8 or 7.";
                        error = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (user_status.equals("")) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide user status as 'active' or 'inactive'";
                error = true;
            }

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select user_id from user_account where mobile_no='" + user_number + "'");
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Mobile number entered is already in use. Please enter a different number.";
                error = true;
            }

            if (!email_id.isEmpty()) {
                String emailReg = "^([\\w-\\.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4})?$";
                if (!email_id.matches(emailReg)) {
                    file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide a valid email address.";
                    error = true;
                } else if (email_id.length() > 30) {
                    file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Please provide email id with length less than 30 characters.";
                    error = true;
                } else {
                    ResultSet resultSet1 = statement.executeQuery("select user_id from user_account where email_id='" + email_id + "'");
                    if (resultSet1.next()) {
                        file_error = file_error + "<br/>XLS Row No." + count + ": Email id entered is already in use. Please choose a different email id.";
                        error = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            ///changes are required
            String user_type_id = null;
            ResultSet resultSet3 = statement.executeQuery("select * from user_type where user_type_name='" + user_type + "'");
            if (resultSet3.next()) {
                user_type_id = resultSet3.getString("user_type_id");
                type.add(user_type_id);
            }

            if (!file_error.equals("")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                URL connectURL = new URL(password_path);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        connectURL.openStream()));

                String inputLine;
                StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    password.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                int uid = 0;
                String encrypted = AESCrypt.bytesToHex(aESCrypt.encrypt(password.toString()));
                passwords.add(password.toString());

                String query = "insert into user_account(user_type_id,first_name,last_name,mobile_no,email_id,status,login_id,password,login_flag,last_gen_pw_ts,last_updated_ts)values('" + user_type_id + "','" + first_name + "','" + last_name + "','" + user_number + "','" + email_id + "','" + user_status + "','" + login_id + "','" + encrypted + "',0,'" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "')";
                //  inserts.add(query);

                statement.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
             //     connection.commit();
                ResultSet rs2 = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (rs2.next()) {
                    uid = rs2.getInt(1);
                }
                if (!group_name.equals("")) {
                    String query1 = "select group_id from user_group where group_name='" + group_name + "'";
                    ResultSet resultset1 = statement.executeQuery(query1);
                    if (resultset1.next()) {
                        int gid = 0;
                        gid = Integer.parseInt(resultset1.getString("group_id"));
                        statement.executeUpdate("insert into user_group_allocation(group_id,user_id,last_updated_ts)values('" + gid + "','" + uid + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "')");
                    } else {
                        int gid = 0;
                        String query4 = "insert into user_group(group_name,group_desc,status,last_updated_ts)values('" + group_name + "','','Active','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "')";
                        statement.executeUpdate(query4, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                        ResultSet rs3 = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
                        if (rs3.next()) {
                            gid = rs3.getInt(1);
                        }
                        statement.executeUpdate("insert into user_group_allocation(group_id,user_id,last_updated_ts)values('" + gid + "','" + uid + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "')");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!file_error.equals("")) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
      connection.commit();

//           for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
//                SendSMS(names.get(i), numbers.get(i), passwords.get(i), login_ids.get(i));
//            }
//            for (int i = 0; i < email_ids.size(); i++) {
//                SendMail(names.get(i), email_ids.get(i), passwords.get(i), login_ids.get(i));
//            }
    }}
```

Comment: Add more info..

Comment: @Sumesh TG added my servlet code

Comment: @Sumesh TG Basically i have multiple inserts inside a loop and autocommit set to false. but when it commits, only last row of the excel is getting inserted to db. Tried debugging the code. Is there any problem with my varibale declaration?

Comment: See `connection.commit();` you are commiting after single insertion . Do this at the end of all process.

Comment: I'm commiting after this while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {} loop @Sumesh TG

Comment: Yes, the problem is your variable declaration You are using a single variable to read from form field so at the end of iteration the value of variable becomes the last row.

Comment: Use POJO class to overcome this issue.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the absolute minimum necessary to reproduce this, a [mcve]. There is too much code in your question to follow.